# AngularJS - $interval is not being fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**header.html**

```
<a ui-sref="fetchAlerts" ng-controller="AlertsCtrl"><img src="./assets/img/alert.png"><span class="badge">{{alertsCount}}</span></a>
```

**AlertsCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('AlertsCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'DummyFactory', function($rootScope, $scope, DummyFactory) {

  $scope.fetchAlerts = function() {
    DummyFactory.getAlerts()          //scala code to fetch background alert
      .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.alerts=data;
        $rootScope.alertsCount=Object.keys($scope.alerts).length;
      })
  };

  $interval( function(){ $scope.fetchAlerts(); }, 3000);

}]);
```

The issue is that my function in `$interval` is not getting called every 3 seconds and hence the `{{alertsCount}}` is not getting updated. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT 1**:

AS suggested, I had injected the `$interval` service. But it refreshes only once. It does not do a continuous refresh. As far I can tell, I was not able to find any errors in the console.

**EDIT 2**:

Calling the `$interval` function with `false` worked! i.e.,
`$interval( function(){ $scope.fetchAlerts(); }, 3000, false)`;

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the debugging console (usually `<F12>` or available through the _Tools_ menu in most browsers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently you forgot to inject `$interval`, update function definition as: `['$rootScope', '$scope', 'DummyFactory', '$interval', function($rootScope, $scope, DummyFactory, $interval)`

Edit: The problem is solved by calling  `$interval` function as `$interval( function(){ $scope.fetchAlerts(); }, 3000, false);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But the update happened only once. After that it does not update the alertsCount variable. Any idea?

Comment: @user2761431 are you sure that `DummyFactory.getAlerts()` resolves different values for `data.alerts.length`? Is it logging data every 3 seconds?

Comment: @JordanMcRae No I did not get any console error. If go to some other page and come back it again updates the value and refreshes once automatically. After that it does not change.

Comment: @CanGuneyAksakalli Yes it logs different values. I print in background to verify. The page is not being refreshed.

Comment: @user2761431 It is supposed to work, check your angular version. I created a simple fiddle to demo it: https://jsfiddle.net/b2omLyn3/3/

Comment: @user2761431 you may try also calling $interval as `$interval( function(){ $scope.fetchAlerts(); }, 3000, false);`

Comment: @CanGuneyAksakalli I will check it, But I modified your code and it seems to not work. Could you point out what is going wrong in this? https://jsfiddle.net/jy0a168p/1/

Comment: @CanGuneyAksakalli Calling with `false` worked! I was following http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/timeout-interval.html and in that it is mentioned that calling `false` will not call `digest()` method. But it seemed like my scenario needed to pass `true` to $interval